# How to get rid of black screen

Tags: android

m Goutham m using android 2.2 i have a problem may be you guys help me in figuring it out.
i have a authentication screen when m logging in it is taking so time to load and then it switches to a black screen and then it goes to the actuall mainscreen. how can i make that black screen to white.. plz help me guys...

Thanx in Advance,
Goutham

Comment: before starting the authentication, show an activity that says "Authenticating..."

Answer (score 2):

Inside your 2nd activity( i.e the page which u load after the login) create

```
private class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // show a progress dialog indicating that its loading
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            // give your code that has to be loaded.
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean success) {
        super.onPostExecute(success);
        //dismiss your progress dialog
    }
}
```

And call this LoginTask in your onCreate function of your 2nd activity as:

```
new LoginTask().execute();
```

Hope this may solve your issue...

Answer (score 0):

simply show a progress dialog
see this.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html
thanks.